# deck not shuffling linked list

Tags: c#, linked-list, shuffle

hi guys i dont know why my shuffle not shuffling. im not getting an error but it not shuffling but when i veiw print my list it comes out sort and not shuffled. can anyone tell me the problem is?  should i put my shuffle in my linked-list instead

my bundle/deck:

```
namespace BlackJack
{
  class Bundle
  {
    //private List<Card> deck1;
    GameLinkedList<Card> deck = new GameLinkedList<Card>();

    public void Shuffle()
    {
        for (int index = 0; index > 52; index++)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            int count = deck.Count();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                int rnd = (int)(r.Next(count));
                deck.AddLast(deck.Delete(rnd));
            }
        }
    }

    public void view()
    {
        deck.Print();
    }
  }
}
```

my linked list:

```
namespace BlackJack
{
  class GameLinkedList<T> where T : IComparable 
  {
    private Node<T> head;
    private Node<T> temp;
    private int count = 0;

    public void Clear()
    {
        head = null;
        count = 0;
    }

    public void Delete(T t)
    {
        Node<T> prev = temp;
        temp = head;

        while (temp != null)
        {
            if (t.CompareTo(temp.data) == 0)
            {
                prev.next = temp.next;
                temp = null;
            }
            else
            {
                prev = temp;
                temp = temp.next;
            }
        }
        count--;
    }

    public T Delete(int i)
    {
        Node<T> prev = temp;
        temp = head;

        while (temp != null)
        {
            if (i.CompareTo(temp.id) == 0)
            {
                prev.next = temp.next;
                count--;
                return temp.data;
            }
            else
            {
                prev = temp;
                temp = temp.next;
            }
        }
        return temp.data;
    }

    public void AddLast(T t)
    {
        if (head == null)
        {
            head = new Node<T>();

            head.data = t;
            head.next = null;
        }
        else
        {
            Node<T> n = new Node<T>();
            n.data = t;

            Node<T> current = head;
            while (current.next != null)
            {
                current = current.next;
            }

            current.next = n;
        }
        count++;
    }

    public int Count()
    {...}

    public void Print()
    {
        temp = head;

        while (temp != null)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(temp.data.ToString());

            temp = temp.next;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the first for?

Comment: we need to make a  card game with our own data structure

Comment: `for (int index = 0; index > 52; index++)`. Your loop doesn't even run once.

Comment: It should also be noted that even when fixed this is a *terrible* shuffling algorithm. There's a 36% chance that the first card will still be first after shuffling.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest reading the [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).

Comment: im getting a nullReferenceException when i go to delete it

Comment: had to use multiple data structures including linked list

Answer (score 0):

Without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, it's impossible to identify every last problem with the code. However, there are a number of obvious problems in just the `Shuffle()` method:

1. Your loop continuation condition is `index > 52`. Since `index` starts at 0, the expression `index > 52` is immediately false, and so the loop won't execute at all.
2. You are allocating a new `Random` object every iteration of the outer loop. This is almost always a bug, because the code will execute so quickly that each new `Random` object will start with the same seed and thus return the same sequence of numbers.
3. You have the outer loop at all. The inner loop should be sufficient for the purposes of this implementation. I.e. the inner loop, for the number of cards in the deck, will select a random card and move it to the end. It's not a good shuffle, but it at least in theory could mix up the cards. Adding the outer loop might increase entropy a bit (if you fix the `Random` bug), but doing so would just add to the inefficiency of the implementation.

It seems to me that you could improve upon your current implementation significantly with some minor changes:

```cs
public void Shuffle()
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int count = deck.Count();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        int rnd = (int)(r.Next(count--));
        deck.AddLast(deck.Delete(rnd));
    }
}
```

In other words, don't bother with the outer loop, and when selecting a new card, don't include any of the cards you've previously selected. By decrementing `count` with each iteration, this will limit the selection of the card to be placed at the end to cards that have not already been selected.